DRV8835 two channels in parallel in IN/IN mode
I'm using a Texas Instruments DRV8835 dual H-bridge IC. This has two output channels, where each channel is an H-bridge (push-pull driver pair).
To use two channels in parallel for higher current capability, the DRV8835 datasheet recommends to connect as follows, which makes sense for the DRV8835's PH/EN mode:
AIN1  + BIN1
AIN2  + BIN2
AOUT1 + BOUT1
AOUT2 + BOUT2

Is it safe to connect it in parallel this way if the DRV8835 is only used in its IN/IN mode?
AIN1  + BIN2
AIN2  + BIN1
AOUT1 + BOUT2
AOUT2 + BOUT1



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@TonyM I'v added schematics, please check

Thanks for editing your question. Have edited further to make it clearer and to add the datasheet link the site requires. If you're satisfied with the answer, you can accept it.

Yes, it's fine to connect the motor drivers in parallel in the way you show.
Each push-pull driver is independently controlled by its input, except for the braking function which drives pairs of outputs LOW when both xINy pins are HIGH. However, you're using the channels in pairs anyway, so braking works just the same - you've just swapped the channels over in the pair.
All in all, what you intend is safe and has no effect on the IC functions.
